# Restric code access in a c# library

Tags: c#, security

I have a library with some critical security related classes.
I want this code not be called by third party applications.

In .Net 2.0 there was an attribute StrongNameIdentityPermissionAttribute but it does not work anymore in .Net 4.0 unless in the app.config we tell the framework to enable legacy CAS like this:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I don't want to use the legacy approach. Are there newest APIs to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522141/prevent-others-from-using-my-dlls, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999830/how-to-secure-dll-functions-from-being-used-outside-of-my-application